# Upload and play a song

Tags: javascript, html, jplayer

i'm trying to upload and play a song with HTML5. I'm using JavaScript to upload the file to the server and jPlayer to play the song but i'm having issues whit this plug-in.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(this)

        .bind("dragenter", function(event) {
                return false;
            })

        .bind("dragover", function(event) {
                return false;
            })

            .bind("drop", function(event) {
                var file = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
            event.preventDefault();
                $("#state").html("Loading...");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    async: true,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                    processData: false,
                    data: file,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#state").html("Ready!");
                $("#player").jPlayer( {
                    ready: function() {
                        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                            oga: file.name
                        }).jPlayer("play");
                    },
                    supplied: "oga"
                });
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    }
            });
            });
    });
```

The file is uploaded to the server, but jPlayer doesn't play it and i can't figure out why...

@vigrond: Yes i can! ;)

```
<html id = "homepage">

    <head>
        <title>Echo</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "upload.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor = "black">
        <div style = "margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
                <h1 style = "margin-top: 100px; color: white">Drag and drop a song...</h1>
                <h2 id = "state" style = "color: white"></h2>
        </div>
        <div id = "player"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you supply your HTML as well?  There are a few steps necessary to get jPlayer to run correctly, and the correct HTML elements is one of them.  You may also want to try setting errorAlerts: true and warningAlerts:true.  This will often give you specific information about what is going on through alert dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue to understand is that all browsers act differently when it comes to HTML5 audio support.  (see here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp)

That is why jPlayer has the flash backup solution.

By default, jPlayer tries the html5 solution first, and falls back to flash with this default setting:

```
solution: "html,flash"  //Set by default, no declaration necessary
```

In order for the flash support to function, you **must** set swfPath to the containing directory of the Jplayer.swf file that jPlayer comes with.

```
swfPath: "/js"
```

Additionally, jPlayer recommends at least 2 different versions of the same file to maximize support for HTML5.  For example, .ogg and .mp3.

```
            $("#player").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        oga: "http://www.vigrond.com/jplayerTest/beer.ogg",
                        mp3: "http://www.vigrond.com/jplayerTest/beer.mp3"
                    }).jPlayer("play");
                },
                supplied: "oga, mp3",
                swfPath: "/js",
                solution: "html,flash"
            });
```

For an example, I set up a test page here of an invisible jPlayer player, with the code and directory structure:  http://vigrond.com/blog/2011/12/01/invisible-html5-flash-audio-player-using-jplayer/

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I knew that, the point is i don't want to use Flash in my website. I'm thinking about convert audio files on the fly in order to maximize cross-browser compatibility.

Today my code is working without any modification though. Guess that yesterday i was testing an older version of the page cached by the browser.

Anyway i have another issue. The uploading script works fine with Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer, but it doesn't work with Safari. When i drag and drop a file, the page upload to the server only 15B and i can't figure out why. Any suggestion?